# PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, encryption

I'm working on a CRAM auth system using a Flash/Flex client and a Java server (Red5). I have used the as3crypto library before, but as far as I know it does not support PBKDF2. This algorithm is suggested for password encryption by NIST so its what I want to use. Does anyone know of an AS3 compatible library with this algorithm, specifically PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1?

Refs:
http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/

http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-132/nist-sp800-132.pdf

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210795/pbkdf2-in-bouncy-castle-c-sharp) question. You might have to implement the algorithm with the the help of as3crypto. It's written in C# however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems OK: http://code.google.com/p/as3-pbkdf2

Comment: Good find, but it looks only to be PBKDF2 and without HMACSHA1

Comment: I think you didn't look enough! It uses HMACSHA1 (PBKDF2.as#L105).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting 'as3 PBKDF2' into google? Took me all of 10 seconds to find these two as they're the top two answers.

The first would suit your needs, but the second seems more versatile as you can specify a hash function.

http://code.google.com/p/as3-pbkdf2/

http://code.google.com/p/as3-pbkdf2-lib/