# How to create a PBKDF2-SHA256 password hash in C# / Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, hash, bouncycastle, password-encryption

I need to create a PBKDF2-SHA256 password hash, but am having some trouble.

I downloaded the [Bouncy Castle](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp) repo, but got a bit stuck finding what I was looking for in the Unit Tests.

Found some sample code [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A6OMjY), but this only does SHA1. The key bit of code is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Computes the PBKDF2-SHA1 hash of a password.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="password">The password to hash.</param>
/// <param name="salt">The salt.</param>
/// <param name="iterations">The PBKDF2 iteration count.</param>
/// <param name="outputBytes">The length of the hash to generate, in bytes.</param>
/// <returns>A hash of the password.</returns>
private static byte[] PBKDF2(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int outputBytes)
{
    var pdb = new Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator();
    pdb.Init(PbeParametersGenerator.Pkcs5PasswordToBytes(password.ToCharArray()), salt,
                 iterations);
    var key = (KeyParameter)pdb.GenerateDerivedMacParameters(outputBytes * 8);
    return key.GetKey();
}
```

I need to change this from SHA1 to SHA256.

From the Java documentation and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15303291/852806), it looked like the following would be possible, but there is no overload on the constructor in the C# library.

```
var pdb = new Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator(new Sha256Derived());
```

Finding [another article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21669357/852806) on stack overflow, i thought the following might be possible, but the SHA hashing algorithms are not in the lookup list ,so the following will not work.

```
var bcparam = (KeyParameter)pdb.GenerateDerivedParameters("sha256", outputBytes * 8);
```

What do I need to do to get this working please?

Note: If you read this and don't know how in Bouncy Castle, but do know another way, I'd still appreciate your help.

Comment: The source code for Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator() is available for you to modify. Why not do it?

Comment: @JamesKPolk - A valid comment. The reasons are: A. Because I don't understand it that well and B. I believe rolling your own in any way is considered a serious no-no when it comes to encryption. However maybe as this is just tampering with the setup it might be ok. I assumed there must be a way, but maybe the C# BouncyCastle is lagging behind the java version and it's just not included? If there really isn't a way to do this in C# then I might try a pull request and update the code, based on the Java version. Would really rather there was something available that I could just use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT** (Previous answer history removed for brevity)

There is now a [Bouncy Castle Crypto API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll/1.8.1) NuGet package that can be used. Alternatively, you can get the [source](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp) directly from GitHub, which will work. I had got the standard Bouncy Castle from NuGet, which had not been updated to 1.8.1 at the time of writing.

For the benefit of searchers, here is a C# helper class for hashing. Have tested on multiple threads and seems fine.

NOTE: This class also works for the .NET Core version of the library [BouncyCastle.NetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.NetCore/)

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains the relevant Bouncy Castle Methods required to encrypt a password.
/// References NuGet Package BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
/// </summary>
public class BouncyCastleHashing
{
    private SecureRandom _cryptoRandom;

    public BouncyCastleHashing()
    {
        _cryptoRandom = new SecureRandom();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Random Salt Creation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size">The size of the salt in bytes</param>
    /// <returns>A random salt of the required size.</returns>
    public byte[] CreateSalt(int size)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[size];
        _cryptoRandom.NextBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a PBKDF2_SHA256 Hash  (Overload)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The password as a plain text string</param>
    /// <param name="saltAsBase64String">The salt for the password</param>
    /// <param name="iterations">The number of times to encrypt the password</param>
    /// <param name="hashByteSize">The byte size of the final hash</param>
    /// <returns>A base64 string of the hash.</returns>
    public string PBKDF2_SHA256_GetHash(string password, string saltAsBase64String, int iterations, int hashByteSize)
    {
        var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(saltAsBase64String);

        var hash = PBKDF2_SHA256_GetHash(password, saltBytes, iterations, hashByteSize);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a PBKDF2_SHA256 Hash (CORE METHOD)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The password as a plain text string</param>
    /// <param name="salt">The salt as a byte array</param>
    /// <param name="iterations">The number of times to encrypt the password</param>
    /// <param name="hashByteSize">The byte size of the final hash</param>
    /// <returns>A the hash as a byte array.</returns>
    public byte[] PBKDF2_SHA256_GetHash(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int hashByteSize)
    {
        var pdb = new Pkcs5S2ParametersGenerator(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Digests.Sha256Digest());
        pdb.Init(PbeParametersGenerator.Pkcs5PasswordToBytes(password.ToCharArray()), salt,
                     iterations);
        var key = (KeyParameter)pdb.GenerateDerivedMacParameters(hashByteSize * 8);
        return key.GetKey();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates a password given a hash of the correct one. (OVERLOAD)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The original password to hash</param>
    /// <param name="salt">The salt that was used when hashing the password</param>
    /// <param name="iterations">The number of times it was encrypted</param>
    /// <param name="hashByteSize">The byte size of the final hash</param>
    /// <param name="hashAsBase64String">The hash the password previously provided as a base64 string</param>
    /// <returns>True if the hashes match</returns>
    public bool ValidatePassword(string password, string salt, int iterations, int hashByteSize, string hashAsBase64String)
    {
        byte[] saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        byte[] actualHashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashAsBase64String);
        return ValidatePassword(password, saltBytes, iterations, hashByteSize, actualHashBytes);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates a password given a hash of the correct one (MAIN METHOD).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The password to check.</param>
    /// <param name="correctHash">A hash of the correct password.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the password is correct. False otherwise.</returns>
    public bool ValidatePassword(string password, byte[] saltBytes, int iterations, int hashByteSize, byte[] actualGainedHasAsByteArray)
    {
        byte[] testHash = PBKDF2_SHA256_GetHash(password, saltBytes, iterations, hashByteSize);
        return SlowEquals(actualGainedHasAsByteArray, testHash);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares two byte arrays in length-constant time. This comparison
    /// method is used so that password hashes cannot be extracted from
    /// on-line systems using a timing attack and then attacked off-line.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">The first byte array.</param>
    /// <param name="b">The second byte array.</param>
    /// <returns>True if both byte arrays are equal. False otherwise.</returns>
    private bool SlowEquals(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        uint diff = (uint)a.Length ^ (uint)b.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length && i < b.Length; i++)
            diff |= (uint)(a[i] ^ b[i]);
        return diff == 0;
    }

}
```

Usage Example

```
public void CreatePasswordHash_Single()
{
    int iterations = 100000; // The number of times to encrypt the password - change this
    int saltByteSize = 64; // the salt size - change this
    int hashByteSize = 128; // the final hash - change this

    BouncyCastleHashing mainHashingLib = new BouncyCastleHashing();

    var password = "password"; // That's really secure! :)

    byte[] saltBytes = mainHashingLib.CreateSalt(saltByteSize);
    string saltString = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);

    string pwdHash = mainHashingLib.PBKDF2_SHA256_GetHash(password, saltString, iterations, hashByteSize);

    var isValid = mainHashingLib.ValidatePassword(password, saltBytes, iterations, hashByteSize, Convert.FromBase64String(pwdHash));

}
```

Comment: confirmed  Bouncy Castle Crypto API nuget package referenced above is now version 1.8.1

Comment: @HockeyJ Hope I'm not late for the party, how to tell what is good number for iterationCount parameter?

Comment: @ramires.cabral - It's a judgement call between speed and security. At one point 4,000 was the norm and would probably still be considered 'secure' today. Apple uses 10,000 for iTunes - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Work_Factor . I chose 100,000 in this example as it is super secure and wouldn't give away the number I actually use when hashing.